# ORMLite AutoIncrement doesn't work in PostgreSQL

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

For some models in ORMLite I use `Guid` as `Primary/Foreign Key` - it allows to do bulk inserts without the need to do `GetLastInsertedId()` after each record inserted. I also use `ShortId` of `int` type for search purposes or passing in URL parameter (like blog post integer id) that should be autoincremented after each insert.

I don't understand how to make `[AutoIncrement]` work on non-primary key column in PostgreSQL.
What I'm doing wrong?

Here is an example of my class:

```
[Alias("ProductProperties")]
public class ProductProperty : IHasShortId, IHasName
{
    public ProductProperty() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [AutoIncrement]
    public int ShortId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(ProductPropertyType))]
    public int PropertyTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

It generates create table script with `short_id` as `integer`, not `serial`:

```
CREATE TABLE product_properties
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  short_id integer NOT NULL,
  name text,
  property_type_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_properties_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_product_properties_product_property_types_PropertyTypeId" FOREIGN KEY (property_type_id)
      REFERENCES product_property_types (short_id) MATCH Unknown
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE product_properties
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

**UPDATE:**

I was able to fix this by patching ORMLite source code:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteConfigExtensions.cs#L127-L128

Commented the `isPrimaryKey &&` line.

Also edited ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteDialectProviderBase.cs lines 385-403

from

```
if (isPrimaryKey)
            {
                sql.Append(" PRIMARY KEY");
                if (autoIncrement)
                {
                    sql.Append(" ").Append(AutoIncrementDefinition);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (isNullable)
                {
                    sql.Append(" NULL");
                }
                else
                {
                    sql.Append(" NOT NULL");
                }
            }
```

to

```
  if (autoIncrement)
        {
            sql.Append(" ").Append(AutoIncrementDefinition);
        }

        if (isPrimaryKey)
        {
            sql.Append(" PRIMARY KEY");
        }
        else
        {
            if (isNullable)
            {
                sql.Append(" NULL");
            }
            else
            {
                sql.Append(" NOT NULL");
            }
        }
```

Why does ORMLite restricts AutoIncrement to primary keys only?